# Updating packages with yum-cron through ebextensions?

Tags: command-line, amazon-ec2, cron, redhat, yum

I'm currently trying to install a package on an Amazon Linux EC2 server. I am trying to use an ebextensions file to set yum-cron to look for package updates daily, but I'm fairly confident that I'm not doing it correctly.

Here's the code in my .config file:

```
  commands:
01do_update_yum:
  command: yum -y update

02install_clamAV:
  command: yum -y install clamav clamd

03install_yum_cron:
  command: yum -y install yum-cron

04install_gedit:
  command: yum -y install gedit

05set_crontab_daily_update:
  command: -c "gedit /etc/yum/yum-cron.conf"

06change_apply_updates:
  command: apply_updates = yes
```

Unless I'm missing something, steps 4 through 6 are not going to work without the user (me) running them. Basically, what I'm wondering, is if anyone knows how I can do what I'm trying to do, but within my .config file.

Thanks so much!
-Matt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your script so the first line reads `container_commands`.

Here's an example I deploy with our builds:

`container_commands:
  yum_update:
    command: yum update -y
    ignoreErrors: true
  install_mysql:
    command: yum install -y mysql
  install_mlocate:
    command: yum install -y mlocate
    ignoreErrors: true
  update_db:
    command: updatedb
    ignoreErrors: true
  install_expect:
    command: yum install -y expect`

See also this example snippet from the [AWS docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#customize-containers-format-container_commands)

`container_commands:
  collectstatic:
    command: "django-admin.py collectstatic --noinput"
  01syncdb:
    command: "django-admin.py syncdb --noinput"
    leader_only: true
  02migrate:
    command: "django-admin.py migrate"
    leader_only: true
  99customize:
    command: "scripts/customize.sh"`